# Ionic 5 Capacitor: Push Notification with ONESIGNAL not working on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, push-notification

I want to use the "onesignal" service to enable push notifications in my Ionic 5 Capacitor App.

For Android everything works fine. 
However, in iOS the device is registered with onesignal but it gets the message "Apns Delegate Never Fired" and its registrated as non-active user without push-subscription.

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work with iOS simulators. I have the same exact error (with OneSignal using flutter), did you fix your problem, and if yes, how ?

Comment: Same issue here, did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

- Add the following capabilities in Xcode: Push Notifications,
  Background Modes -> Background Fetch & Remote notifications
- Disable the Capacitor Push Notifications plugin by removing all "USE_PUSH" and "DEBUG USE_PUSH" compilation conditions under the targets build settings (see the plugin documentation here for more details on how to disable the plugin: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/push-notifications/)
- Test with Testflight and *not* directly with Xcode. I don't know why, but it only works while testing with Testflight. With Xcode, the problem persists.

Comment: Hey moritz.vieli, Zhank for your help! I will implement your solution soon and report back.